# How to save new default settings for Mantaflow?

Tags: startup-file, mantaflow

In Blender I changed some of the default settings to my preferred values and saved them to my startup file, like using *Cycles* instead of *Eevee*, the default *Tile Size*, *Max Bounces*, enabling *Use Nodes* and *Backdrop* in the *Compositor* for example.

But since the latest versions I've got problems with Mantaflow crashing when it uses the default *Blosc* compression for the cache files, as described here:

[Mantaflow: bake always crashes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214921/mantaflow-bake-always-crashes-cannot-be-resumed)

Now I'd like to know if there is a way to save the default compression type to *Zip* - because even though I've identified the problem it still happens that I bake and forget to change it which makes Blender crash again and lose the simulation data.

I could do it by saving my startup file having the default cube be a domain with the desired setting, but I don't always want to start with a Mantaflow simulation. Setting the compression to *Zip*, deleting the domain and saving the startup file afterwards doesn't store the compression type, because then creating a new domain will use the default value *Blosc* again.