# Blender 2.92.0 crashing a lot during fluid simulation baking

Tags: fluid-simulation

Any fix for this? It appears to happen more often when "adaptive domain" is enabled, but not exclusively.
Turning on 'noise' also appears to make it more likely of crashing.

It's not RAM, I have 32GB of RAM and only like 20% is being used during baking.

Comment: Impossible to give any advice based on this question IMHO. If blender crashes and you're able to reproduce the crash, please file a bug report (Help > Report a Bug).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if my problem with the Mantaflow Smoke Simulation does apply here because it was independent from *Adaptive Domain* or *Noise*, only related to the domain resolution.

But in the latest releases my smoke simulations crashed every time I used domain resolutions like 120 or higher. The problem is that in the *Cache Settings* under *Format Volumes* > *OpenVDB* there are now *Advanced Settings* that you can expand. There you find *Compression Volumes* set to "Blosc" by default.

Now "Blosc" might be the best or most efficient compression, but this makes my simulation bake crash with not-so-low-resolutions. Setting it to "Zip" or "None" lets me bake even with resolutions of 500 and *Adaptive Domain*.

Read my original answer to my problem here, I cannot yet verify if it helps for *Liquid* simulations since my computer is occupied, but the "Blosc" setting is there, too:

[Mantaflow bake alaways crashes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/219676/99859)

Comment: Thanks! I will try and if it works I'll mark your answer as the right answer!

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work in my case. Thanks for sharing your experience though, might be useful to someone else.